# How to chain commands

Tags: command-line

How to chain commands, i.e. make the output of one command become the input of another?

```
basename | dirname /dev/null
```

Expected Output:

```
dev
```

Actual Output:

```
usage: basename string [suffix]
       basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]
/dev
```

Also tried the following but it also did not work:

```
dirname /dev/null | basename
```

Comment: basename needs an argument.  If you removed the `| dirname /dev/null` from your command and typed only `basename` you'll get the same error message.  Are you trying to get the base of the name "/dev/null"?  Try `basename /dev/null`.

Comment: @SottoVoce I am trying to get the name of the parent directory of a file path.

Comment: Then you want `dirname /dev/null`, which will return `/dev`.  Are you trying to get `dev` without the leading `/`?  `basename` doesn't read its string from standard input like that.  It looks for the string on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
basename "$(dirname /dev/null)"
```

Though for arbitrary file paths where you can't guarantee path components won't start with `-`, you'd need to add some `--`s to mark the end of options:

```
basename -- "$(dirname -- "$file")"
```

`$(...)` can be used to run a command and collect output to be used as a command line parameter to another program.

Beware that since `$(...)` removes *all* the trailing newline characters from the output of commands, the above still doesn't work for arbitrary file paths; in the example above, those whose dirname ends in newline characters. Working around that, though possible, is painful enough that the problem is usually left ignored.

In the zsh shell, one can use csh-style modifiers to get the `t`ail (basename) or `h`ead (dirname) of files which don't have the issue:

```
tail_of_head=$file:h:t
```

Those modifiers are also available in `vim`. They are also available in `bash`, but only for history expansion, not parameter expansion like in csh or zsh.

Comment: This worked thanks.